# CSS not working as it should

Tags: html, css

I am not a web developer but can read around a CSS file and implement it. I have some CSS below that works correct except for .topbox whenever I try to use that in a div, it just shows up as normal text not the CSS style, I tried reloading the browser cache, I even tried copying and pasting some of the CSS that works and changing the name but even that doesn't work. So that leaves me to believe that there is an error somewhere in my CSS causing this issue.

```
.redbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(170,75,75,0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(61,60,60,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(168,10,10,0.45);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
.topbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(152,0,0,0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(224,102,102,0.7);
}
```

Trying to implement it like so;

```
<div class="topbox">
    Test<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

That will not work, it just shows up as regular text. However..

```
<div class="redbox">
    Test<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

Shows up just fine.. any thoughts?

EDIT: Trying to make this more clear what is going on..

This is what happens using class="redbox" from the code above..

[image: Exactly what I expect..]

However, when I COPY AND PASTE THE EXACT SAME .redbox CSS to .topbox and I would expect the same result.. this is what I get..

[image: I have class="topbox" but I changed the .topbox CSS code to match .redbox, so why is it not showing up the way the above does?]

Here is the updated CSS

```
.redbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(170,75,75,0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(61,60,60,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(168,10,10,0.45);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}

.topbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(165,161,74,0.65);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(61,60,60,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(153,148,7,0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
```

But .redbox displays as expected and .topbox just displays without and CSS formatting..

Comment: What do you mean by "shows up as normal text not the CSS style"? Can you use the Stack Snippets with a [mcve] which shows the problem? Please include what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: I edited my above questions to better show what is happening. Using the snippet would be difficult since this is part of a large flask project.

Comment: It seems this was an issue with the CSS not getting updated on reload. I cleared cached and everything in chrome and it still did not work. I had to download an extension to reload the CSS. No idea what was going on.. It was driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.greenbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;  
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(76,173,76,0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(63,63,63,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(10,170,10,0.45);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
.redbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(170,75,75,0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(61,60,60,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(168,10,10,0.45);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
.bluebox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(75,120,168,0.65);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(61,60,60,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(7,87,153,0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
.yellowbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid rgba(165,161,74,0.65);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(61,60,60,0.85);
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(153,148,7,0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
.footer {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 15px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3) ;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
}
.topbox {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(152,0,0,0.7);
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font: normal 14px/1 Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(224,102,102,0.7);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="topbox">
    Test<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</div>

<div class="greenbox">
    Test<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: I apologize, it is in it's own document, and all the CSS besides .topbox work fine in it. I am not sure what is causing .topbox to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was an issue with Chrome not reloading the CSS for some reason even tho I cleared cache and tried crtl+f5, etc. I had to download an extension.. 'reload CSS' for chrome to have it work.